# Removing rows from a matrix A if they are contained in matrix B

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix, say `A = perms([1 2 3 4])`. I have another matrix, say `B = [1 2 3 4; 4 3 1 2; 2 4 3 1]`. How do I remove the rows `[1 2 3 4]`, `[4 3 1 2]` and `[2 4 3 1]` (i.e. the rows of `B`) from `A`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This solution maintains the row order:

```
A(find(ismember(A, B, 'rows')),:) = [];
```